# Menu items in Lightning Experience is in alphabetical order rather than logical order.

Tags: lightning-experience, setup, menu

Just curious to see the menu items in the Lightning Experience setup is in alphabetical order rather than logical order as it is in Salesforce classic. Usually, it starts with Users, Profiles, etc... Is that something we can do to get it in the logical order? Please advice. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The new Setup screen is designed to be alphabetical intentionally to make it easier to find items. I realize that people that are used to Classic have been "trained" over the past 19 years to accept the rather chaotic ordering of Setup, but the new UI is arguably better, since it is alphabetical, which is usually a lot easier for us humans to scan through.